# lighttpd password protecting URL webpage

Tags: passwords, lighttpd, mod-auth

I am trying to add some basic measures of security to the main webpage of my Raspberry Pi project hosted by lighttpd.

I have been looking into the `mod_auth` plugin and have tried a few things however I am having some issues getting the username and password prompt to pop up when I visit my webpage.

I have a `.txt` file called `details.txt` located under `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.users` containing my own simple username and password in the form `RobotUser:**********`

**lighttpd .conf file**

```
server.modules = (
                   *
                   *
                   *          
                   *
                   "mod_auth",
                 )  

***********************************************************  

auth.backend = "plain"
auth.backend.plain.userfile = "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.users"
auth.require = ( "10.152.1.105" =>
( "method"   => "basic",
  "realm"    => "Authorised Users Only",
  "require"  => "user=RobotUser"
))
```

Now when I head over to my webpage via the IP address there is no prompt for username and password.  If i change the IP to a directory such as `var/www`, where my html webpage is located and then access `http://MY_IP/var/www/` the prompt pops up however my username and password entry from the `.txt` file does not seem to pass the prompt.

Any ideas? This is my first time tackling something like this and through various google searches i can't overcome this step.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for lighttpd mod_auth.  Where you have an IP address in the config, lighttpd takes a url-path, not an IP address and not a directory path on disk.  Use "/details.txt" instead if you only want to protect that url-path.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth

If you only want to allow access from a single IP address, see mod_access

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAccess